# Using PythonKit in multi-threaded app crashes app

Tags: python, swift, swift-pythonkit

For several reasons it is required to call the python functions from parallel threads, currently PythonKit library is being used for that. While one python module is running and if I try to execute the other module from other thread than it is giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. this error from internal code of PythonKit.

Please guide me if I am missing something.
As the error is from internal code I am pasting a screenshot.[image]

Comment: I don't see any indication that PythonKit is threadsafe.

Comment: @TimRoberts is there any standard way to validate that PythonKit is not threadsafe?
Is there any other solution for such scenarios where I need to execute multiple python modules simultaneously?

Comment: As of November 2020, it was not threadsafe.  https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/g/swift/c/r7nZg1JRF7E

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks a lot to point out to this thread. can you please post it as an answer rather than comment so I mark it as answered.
Thanks Again.